# List frontend IP of Azure Internal Loadbalancer and Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

I am trying to pull an inventory of all the frontend IP addresses of Azure Internal Loadbalancer and Application Gateway and export them to a spreadsheet. I tried looking up, but the most results tend to be towards pulling the Public IP information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Azure CLI the following command will pull the desired information. Make sure to be in the right subscription or add the parameter for it

Load Balancer

```
az network lb list --query "[].{ name: name, privateIpAddresses: join(', ', frontendIpConfigurations[*].privateIpAddress) }" -o tsv
```

Application Gateway

```
az network lb list --query "[].{ name: name, privateIpAddresses: join(', ', frontendIpConfigurations[*].privateIpAddress) }" -o tsv
```